# Looking to consolidate 3 xls files in one. And paste the values of consolidated file into Master file

Tags: excel, vba

I have data in 3 XLS files named AM,MD,PM. I want to consolidate all the 3 XLS file into 1 XLS file using VBA.

Also the data which is there in these 3 XLS files I only want from a particular Row And column. Say for example from cell A41 to A53 B41 to B53 untill U41 to U53 for all the 3 files. As a result I want a xls file to be consolidatedly generate with only the rows and columns I need leaving remaing.

After I generate this consolidated file, I want to import these values into a master template XLS file. So when I click a button on master Excel template file it should consolidate 3 XLS files generate one file and should reflect its values in the master template XLS file.[enter image description here][1]

[enter image description here][2]

enter image description here

```
Sub loopthroughDirectory()

Dim Myfile As String

Dim erow

Myfile = Dir("Path")


Do While Len(Myfile) > 0

If Myfile = "zmaster.xlsm" Then

Exit Sub
End If


Workbooks.Open (Myfile)
Range("A41:T53").Copy
ActiveWorkbook.Close


erow = car.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Car").Range(Cells(erow, 1), 

Cells(erow, 20))


Myfile = Dir

Loop

End Sub
```

But this is not working. It is able to open the files but the values are not being pasted in the consolidated file which I am trying to generate.
Suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: I would identify the source workbook and to workbook as variables that way VBA understands what data is moving from one workbook to the other.

Comment: Are your ranges static?

Comment: @ JVBA no the range is not static.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer selecting files through File Dialog Box for consistency and reliable results, but at the cost of few seconds multi selecting the file. Working code for your situation would be some thing like this :

```
Option Explicit

Sub Consolidation()

Dim CurrentBook As Workbook
Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim wsn As Worksheet
Set WS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("car")
Dim IndvFiles As FileDialog
Dim FileIdx As Long
Dim i As Integer, x As Integer

Set IndvFiles = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)'Select your AM,Md, Pm files here
With IndvFiles
    .AllowMultiSelect = True
    .Title = "Multi-select target data files:"
    .ButtonName = ""
    .Filters.Clear
    .Filters.Add ".xls files", "*.xls"
    .Show
End With

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For FileIdx = 1 To IndvFiles.SelectedItems.Count
    Set CurrentBook = Workbooks.Open(IndvFiles.SelectedItems(FileIdx))
   Set wsn = CurrentBook.Sheets(1)
        Dim LRow1 As Long
        LRow1 = WS.Range("A" & WS.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Dim LRow2 As Long
        LRow2 = CurrentBook.ActiveSheet.Range("A" & CurrentBook.ActiveSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        Dim ImportRange As Range
        Set ImportRange = CurrentBook.ActiveSheet.Range("A41:T53")' As per yr code adjust if required
        ImportRange.Copy
        WS.Range("A" & LRow1 + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    'Next
    CurrentBook.Close False
Next FileIdx

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: @sam Glad to note that it works fine for you. Please accept my Answer. To mark an answer as accepted, please click on the check mark beside the answer and below lower pointing triangle  to toggle it from greyed out to filled in. Thanks.

Comment: I have one change which needs to be done. And I would appreciate if you could try help me out with it. I have posted that question is there a way I can copy that link to you so that you have a look at it and let me know if you could help me out in it?

Comment: Want to Copy And Paste Data In Master file and it should find the appropriate column in master file        Please type this in the serach bar and it will take you to the question I am referring to.

Comment: @sam I have located your question posted an hour ago.. I shall look into it a little later after  finishing my urgent work .

Comment: Ok sure. Thank you for your help. Really Appreciate it.

Comment: Do you think is there a way out to solve the problem which i am trying to solve ? Whenever you get free please have a look at the problem. Deeply in need of help. Thank you